# How to ignore messages until after on_ready finishes in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot using discord.py, and I ran into some problems. I have a rather large database that needs initialising every time the bot starts to register the new servers/players. And that process takes a long time (20-30s). I am initialising the database inside the `on_ready` method, so I can have access to all the guilds. And as a result, all the commands that users used during that period are queued and my bot will then "burst" out all the responses for each of the commands. I want to be able to completly ignore messages sent during that initialisation process, to prevent possible rate limits on certain APIs.

I have tried searching on Google/StackOverflow and looking through discord.py docs, but sadly, no results.

here is my code:

```py
async def on_ready(self):
    logger.info("INITIALISING DATABASE...")

    self.init_guilds()
    # initialising other data, takes about 20-30s

    logger.info("CLIENT LOGIN")

async def on_message(self, message);
    if message.author.bot or not isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        return

    msg = message.content.strip()
    if len(msg) > 1 and msg[0] == '_':
        await handler.handle(message, self)  # I am using a custom command handler instead of discord.ext.commands
```

Comment: You could just have a flag attribute that defaults to False, then after `init_guilds` set it back to True, and then on_message checks ``if False: return``

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I added a variable called `db_initialised` that defaults to False, and after init_guilds I set it to true. I checked it in the if statment inside on_message.

Comment: Without seeing how you did it, I cannot say but I'm fairly confident that this is how you just ignore/drop messages before its done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async def on_connect(self):
    print("Initialising database...")
    self.init_guilds()

async def on_ready(self):
    print(f"{self.user} is ready!")

async def on_message(self, message):
    if not self.is_ready():
        return
```

Comment: I writed the `self.init_guilds()` because you are starting initialize after bot is ready up.

Comment: Thank you. It not only works, but also speeds up the initialisation process by almost 20 seconds for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a flag which indicates if the database is initialized (set it to `False` by default), after you connect to the database set it to `True`. Inside the error handler check whether it's set to `True`:

```py
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.db_connected = False
    ...


async def on_ready(self):
    logger.info("INITIALISING DATABASE...")

    self.init_guilds()
    # initialising other data, takes about 20-30s

    logger.info("CLIENT LOGIN")
    self.db_connected = True


async def on_message(self, message):
    if not self.db_connected:
        return

    if message.author.bot or not isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
        return

    msg = message.content.strip()
    
    if len(msg) > 1 and msg[0] == '_':
        await handler.handle(message, self)
```

PS: Connecting to your database and/or making API requests in the `on_ready` event is a bad idea, from the docs:

> This function is not guaranteed to be the first event called. Likewise, this function is not guaranteed to only be called once. This library implements reconnection logic and thus will end up calling this event whenever a `RESUME` request fails.

Unless you implement some kind of logic to prevent the event to be called more than once (like another flag or a decorator), I wouldn't recommend you connecting to the database there.